# How to make points more compact using fastpoint chart in

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I am new to C# winform. As title, my problem is how to make the points more compact in fastpoint chart. To make it clear, how to proportionally reduce the distance of the blue points like the red line segments shown in the image; that is, make the X axis more compact:

[image]

I have searched and found a lot of information about control the interval of X or Y axis labels but which is not the situation here.

Comment: You can try to reduce the XAxis.Interval or the XAxis.Maximum..

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have printed out the values of AxisX.Interval and AxisX.Maximun but get the result of 0 and NaN respectively. I am still thinking what's wrong with it.

Comment: NaN is the defualt (for many chart properties) and it means: Automatic. If you want to change the automatic look you can set theose properties. If you set the xaxis.Maximum to 200 the data will be compressed to half the width.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. It works in this case! Sorry if the data of X axis is in DateTime format, how to adjust AxisX.Maximun?

Comment: You can use the conversion functions to go between double and DataTime: `ax.Minimum =  dt.ToOADate();
            ax.Maximum = (dt.AddHours(24)).ToOADate();` Note that you may want to to set the types of the axis but also of the Interval!

Comment: Great! You have totally solved my problem, thanks a lot! How to upvote your answer?

Comment: OK, I think I have done it! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the range of data values for each `Axis` by setting their `Minimum` and `Maximum` values.

The syntax is:

```
someChart.ChartAreas[CAIndexOrName].AxisX.Minimum = someDoubleValue;
```

Let's prepare a chart to show one day:

```
Axis ax = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;   // a short reference

ax.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
ax.Interval = 1;
```

To set the properties to some `DateTime` values you need to convert them to doubles; for this conversion there are two built-in functions: [`DateTime.ToOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx) and, to reverse  [`DateTime.FromOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This makes the x-axis display 24 hours:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;

ax.Minimum =  dt.ToOADate();
ax.Maximum = (dt.AddHours(24)).ToOADate();

ax.LabelStyle.Format = "H:mm";   // optional
```

You also may want to control the data type of the series values:

```
 Series s = chart.Series[0];
 s.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;  // or some other type, maybe Time
```

Note you you can also control both the `Interval` of the `Labels` and `TickMarks` and `Gridlines` on each axis but also set an `Offset` to start them a little earlier or later..